# indexOf for space in string

Tags: java, string, find, space

There is a space in the string, but when I run program, it returns -1, that means there aren't spaces in the string
Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String s = scan.next();
         System.out.println(s.indexOf(' '));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Scanner.next()` returns the next token in the input, and by default, tokens are whitespace separated. i.e. `s` is guaranteed not to contain spaces.

Maybe you meant `String s = scan.nextLine();`?

Answer (score 6):

this perfectly works fine for me.

```
System.out.println("one word".indexOf(' '));
```

This is because of Scanner next method. [check this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101101200016AArUCya)

Answer (score 3):

Scanner reads text seperated by whitespace, which can be a line break but also a space character. This is why scan.next() will return a String with no spaces. If you need line breaks instead, use scan.nextLine()

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

as scan.next() gets the next "word" which can't contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scan.nextLine()` because `scan.next()` will read until it encounters a white space (tab, space, enter) so it finish getting when it see space. You yourself could guess this by printing s, too!
be successful!